# copy, replace folder and files, so that keep both changed files and remove one of identical files

Tags: windows-10, copy, replacement

I have many copied version of files and folders.
I want to merge folder and files but keep the all changed version of same name files and remove all identical files and only keep one version.

for example(I have two folder as below):

folder 1 =  a.txt (1kb),  b.txt(2kb), c.txt (3kb)

folder 2 =  a.txt (1kb),  b.txt(5kb), c.txt (3kb)

I want this merged folder:

a.txt (1kb),  b.txt(2kb),  b (2).txt(5kb), c.txt (3kb)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Operating system: Microsoft windows 10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it is easy. only I need to copy and replace identical files and do not replace same name files with different size